# How to value VIX Option?

Tags: vix

Could someone tell me a common method for pricing VIX Options please?

Do I need to use a Stochastic Vol Model? Or Local Vol Model is suitable as well?

Should the model be modelling S&P 500 and then recalculate the VIX Index? Or model the VIX Index directly?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand exactly how the VIX index is derived?

Comment: Market makers commonly just treat these as "normal" options that happen to have an unusual skew.  This is a roundabout way of asking: what will your hypothetical pricing method be used for?

Answer (score 2):

I am ignorant to VIX option pricing but I would start with this: [The performance of VIX option pricing models: Empirical evidence beyond simulation](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/fut.20466/abstract?deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=&userIsAuthenticated=false) -- Working paper [version](https://msb040.msb.edu/faculty/bodurthj/unrestricted/teaching/articles/Derivatives/options/Wang-Daigler_The%20Performance%20of%20VIX%20Option%20Pricing%20Models-Empirical%20Evidence%20Beyond%20Simulation_2009.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There's ongoing debate about whether SPX and VIX options contain different valuable information (see [Bardgett Gourier Leippold (2013) - Inferring Volatility Dynamics and Risk Premia from the S&P 500 and VIX Markets](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2296826) among recently contributions). I would say this is slightly counterintuitive (VIX index is calculated as a portfolio of SPX vanilla), but at the same time, is the fact that VIX derivatives provide a pure volatility exposure (and traders know it much better than me) that make them conveying a different information, at least concerning volatility dynamics. This said, I would use a consistent model calibrated on both markets. Moreover, in the context of VIX options, there's no Dupire equation (linking VIX option Prices to a VIX implied local volatiliy), but - in some sense parallel - there's an approach called the *standalone* approach (see [Mencìa Sentana (2012)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1524193) for an update reference), in which one models directly the VIX (without care of the S&P500 market). I would use this If you need a pure pricing machine. But, a *structural* model as the one I mentioned before is needed to have a perspective of the market as a whole (e.g. estimate risk premia).
To conclude, you could off course even simply interpolate the VIX implied surface as is common practice in SPX context. But I don't think this what you meant.